# swift2 loading contents of text file into variable

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, xcode7.2

I am trying to fill an array by loading it from a text file and then separating the text with line breaks to formulate an array however i am getting an error "Expected Expression"

```
  var marrCountryList = [String]()
  try!  var text = String(contentsOfFile: "country", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  marrCountryList = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `try` is not in the right position:

```
do {
     contentsOfFile = try String(contentsOfFile: "country", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch {
    print(error);
    contentsOfFile = nil;
}
```

Also when you use a try you must have a `do` and `catch`

Comment: The do and catch blocks are not required when using try. It is also possible to make an optional assignment based on the success of the operation: `var contentsOfFile = try? String(contentsOfFile: "country", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`. `contentsOfFile` will then be of the type `String?`.